# Solidity 'out of gas' exception when trying to transfer Ether

Tags: solidity, transfer, ether

I try to transfer Ether from the contract to an address but it gives the error that the transaction is out of gas. I think it's a small problem but I can't find it. I have to specifically use solidity version 0.4.24.

[The warning from Remix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CgCk.png)

[The error from MetaMask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H02yT.png)

I have tried different methods, like:

```
address.transfer(amount);
address.send(amount);
address.call.value(amount)( );
```

All methods will give the same out of gas exception. and the send and call method will also give a warning that it's outdated and that I should use the transfer method.

I also tried to adjust the gas and it didn't work, I also tried the needed 2,300 for the transfer listed on the [docs](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/units-and-global-variables.html#address-related).

The code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract TestContract {        
    function payAddress(address _address) external payable {
         _address.transfer(msg.value);
    }
}
```

If the problem is that the contract doesn't have any Ether to transfer, can it use the Ether I send with the function call? Or is the problem something else?

Thank you for reading.

**edit:**

I have tried to send Ether to my Contract and that works, I do have Ether on my contract now, but the function still gives the same error as before. So the problem is something else.

Current code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract TestContract {

    function() external payable { }

    function payContract() public payable {}

    function paySomeone(address _address, uint256 _amount) external {
         _address.transfer(_amount);
    }

    function getBalance() public view returns (uint256) {
         return address(this).balance;
   }

}
```

[The balance of the contract](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s54Kp.png)

[The parameters I use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHVN7.png)

[Same MetaMask error as before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pbfL.png)

As you can see here the balance of the contract is 10 wei, but when i try to send 9 wei it still gives the same out of gas error. I also still get the same error from Remix as before.

Comment: @GeertBraakman, could you share more about how you're testing this code? Are you testing in the JavaScript VM, via some local network, on a test network, etc.? What gas limit are you specifying when you call the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also post the issue on the Stack exchange and got an answer there. The issue was my 
Ganache version. I switched to the Robsten test network and it worked. I'll link the post [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/65234/solidity-out-of-gas-exception-when-trying-to-transfer-ether).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In order to send ether from contract to another address, first you must send some ether to the contract address. Take a look at [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/17378/48372) and [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15420/how-to-send-ether-to-contracts-address).

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help, I tried it but it didn't work. I edited my post with the new code.